# Is it possible to stack a list of ragged arrays (where each array in the list is of size 1 row and n columns)?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, stack, ragged

I have a list of arrays.

```
[array([   2.,    4.,    6.,    8.,   10.,   12.,   14.,   16.,   18.,
         20.,   22.,   24.,   26.,   28.,   30.,   32.,   34.,   36.,
         38.,   40.,   42.,   44.,   46.,   48.,   50.,   52.,   54.,
         56.,   58.,   60.,   62.,   64.,   66.,   68.,   70.,   72.,
         74.,   76.,   78.,   80.,   82.,   84.,   86.,   88.,   90.,
         92.,   94.,   96.,   98.,  100.]), array([   4.,    8.,   12.,   16.,   20.,   24.,   28.,   32.,   36.,
         40.,   44.,   48.,   52.,   56.,   60.,   64.,   68.,   72.,
         76.,   80.,   84.,   88.,   92.,   96.,  100.]), array([  8.,  16.,  24.,  32.,  40.,  48.,  56.,  64.,  72.,  80.,  88.,
        96.])]
```

I have tried `np.vstack` to stack the list array by array. But because the arrays are not of equal size (ie, different number of columns), I received this error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

I do not want to concatenate them because I want to store the rows for future computations. How can I stack them row by row if the rows are ragged?

Edit: Is it possible to concatenate along a variable axis for this purpose?

Comment: In `numpy` 'stack' is the same as 'concatenate', with name variations for style.  All refer to joining array into a larger array along some axis.

Comment: What's wrong your list of arrays? There is an object dtype array, but for most purposes is it's functionally the same as a list.  `hdf5` has arrays with a variable axis, `numpy` does not.

Comment: The size of my actual dataset is several thousand `1 x n` arrays, each consisting of floats instead of integers. If I can stack each array row by row, then it will be easier to do a future calculation per each row. I was also hoping to be able to read them easier on a print screen, but that's not as important.

Comment: I will look into `hdf5`, thanks.

Comment: A ragged `h5py` example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658438/storing-multidimensional-variable-length-array-with-h5py/; notice that when loaded into `numpy` it becomes an object dtype array.  You can't perform 'row' calculations in an object array as well as you can in a regular 2d array.  And don't expect any speed improvements compared to list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(i) for i in yourlist])
```

The result will be something like this:

[image]

The drawback is that you will have to deal with the missing values while doing your calculations.