# Fastest way to go through a long list of arrays

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I have a data set from electrophysiological recordings in a hdf5 file in the form of what is really close to numpy arrays from my understanding and what I am trying to do is access it in the most efficient and fast way.

**Let me explain:** The dataset is a list of arrays (2D-array?); each array contains x number of channels (recording sites), usually around 32-64.

**The problem is the following:** There are millions of arrays and it's taking forever to loop through every individual array. Moreover, I have to loop through each channel in each array in order retrieve the values.

Here is my code:

```
import h5py

f_kwd = h5py.File("experiment1_100.raw.kwd", "r") # reads hdf5 file
dset_data = f_kwd['recordings/0/data']
print (len(dset_data)) # prints 31646700
print (dset_data[0]) # prints the following

[    94   1377    208    202    246    387   1532   1003    460    665
810    638    223    363    990     78   -139    191     63    630
763     60    682   1025    472   1113   -137    360   1216    297
-71    -35   -477   -498   -541   -557  27776   2281 -11370  32767
-28849 -30243]

list_value = []
for t_stamp in (dset_data):
    for value in t_stamp:
        if value > 400:
            list_value.append(value)
```

Is there a way to make this a lot more efficient and quick?
Do I have to use numpy and if so, how can I make this happen? I feel like I am doing something wrong here.

**EDIT :**
Here are some additional info about the  first array in dataset for the following attributes:

> .shape -> (42,)
>   .itemsize -> 2
>   .dtype -> int16
>   .size -> 42
>   .ndim -> 1

**EDIT2 :**
..and the dataset itself:

> .shape -> (31646700, 42)
>   .dtype -> int16
>   .size -> 1329161400

Comment: We need to know more about the dataset.  In `h5py` a set may be 2d with 1 variable dimension, i.e a ragged 2d array.  But `numpy` 2d arrays have to be rectangular.  A ragged set is loaded as 1d numpy with object dtype.  Access to such an array is slower. In MATLAB is that array being loaded as a `cell`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658438/storing-multidimensional-variable-length-array-with-h5py - A SO question about variable length array.

Comment: How about information for the dataset as a whole, not just one 'row'?

Comment: Do you have a chunked Dataset? If so, what is the chunk size of your Dataset? Do you really have a list of arrays of variable length? It looks like you are having one array with shape  (31646700, 42)...

Answer (score 1):

If my guess that `t_stamp` is a 1d array of varying length, you could collect all elements >400 with:

```
list_value = []
for t_stamp in (dset_data):
    list_value.append(t_stamp[t_stamp>400])
    # list_value.extend()
```

Use `append` if you want to collect the values in sublists. Use extend if you want one flat list.

It still iterates on the 'rows' of `dset_data`, but selection from each row will be much faster.

If all rows are 42 long, then `dset_data.value` will be a 2d numpy array:

```
dset_data[dset_data>400]
```

will be a flat array of the selected values

Answer (score 0):

this may help. first change nd arry to 1d arry; second sorted it; third find index of number. In this case, you do need iterate all the items.

```
import numpy as np

newData = dset_data.ravel()
newData.sort()
index = np.searchsorted(data,400)
res = newData[:index ]
```